# Flattening Nested dictionary into Dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to flatten out a nested dictionary into a pandas dataframe. I tried a few of the other answers for multiple datasets but they're all close but not quite what I want.

I would appreciate some help on figuring out the best way this may be flattened.

Here is an example of the dictionary's entries:

```
data = {1:{
      'Name': "Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers",
      'IDs':{
            "StoreID": ['123445452543'],
            "BookID": ['543533254353'],
            "SalesID": ['543267765345']},
     2:{
      'Name': "boring Tales of Dragon Slayers",
      'IDs':{
            "StoreID": ['111111', '1121111'],
            "BookID": ['543533254353', '4324232342'],
            "SalesID": ['543267765345', '4353543']}}
```

Here is the intended output from this

```
Name                                StoreID        BookID          SalesID
Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers   123445452543   543533254353    543267765345
```

All help is appreciated. Thank you so much :)

edit:
Thank you for the effort so far, I reevaluated according to the answer I've received so far. The data I have is loaded in via a pkl file I was under the assumption that given its format (as shown above) and the fact that it was originally a nested dictionary it would be able to be flattened out the same. This does not seem to be the case. Apologies if this messes with current efforts.

Comment: is that example cover all use cases?, also can you correct your syntax? the `1:` doesnt make sense

Comment: @adirabargil The `1:` in the entry is because that is how the dictionary is formatted, I didn't create it, I am just working on it. Its incremental so the next would be `2:` and so on. The example roughly covers all the cases, there are some which have (for example) multiple store IDs or Sales IDs but that shouldn't change much,,, right?

Comment: can you show us more then? change your question accordingly and fix your syntex issue

Answer (score 2):

assuming this is the example that covers the issue:

```
example_dict = {
1:{ 'Name': "Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers",
     'IDs':{
            "StoreID": ['11','31'],
            "BookID": ['12','32'],
            "SalesID": ['13','33']}},
2:{ 'Name': "Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers2",
     'IDs':{
            "StoreID": ['21'],
            "BookID": ['22'],
            "SalesID": ['23']}}
}
```

here is a solution you can use to create a df:

```
flat_dict = [
    dict(Name=item["Name"],StoreID=item['IDs']["StoreID"][i],BookID=item['IDs']["BookID"][i],SalesID=item['IDs']["SalesID"][i]) 
     for item in example_dict.values() 
    for i in range(len(item['IDs']["StoreID"])) 
]
df = pd.DataFrame(flat_dict)
```

Output of `df`:

```
    Name                                StoreID BookID  SalesID
0   Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers   11      12      13
1   Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers   31      32      33
2   Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers2  21      22      23
```

Comment: So this seemingly should work, however I end up getting an error stating 'tuple indicies must be integers of slices, not str'

Comment: its not in this specific example, can you give more information?

Comment: Ok I understand where I messed up with my initial writing, the error is still the same, instead of 'tuple' it is 'value' (I'd used item instead of values)  I think the latest information I added to the question may help as well. This is a dictionary from an imported file so I'm thinking it may not be able to be recognized the same way as a normal dictionary.

Comment: try to print it

Comment: I don't think that would solve it - the error sits in the loop specifically on `for i in range(len(item["IDs"]["StoreID"]))` which triggers the error

Comment: if you print `item["IDs"]` we can see the problem

Comment: printing `item["ID"]` outputs `name 'item' is not defined`

Comment: it seems that you need to learn some python essentials... i am up to explain in private what u need...